# jQuery-Ui resizable: div size limited to magical borders

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable, jquery-ui-resizable

when i try to resize a div container (`#draggableItem`) after dropping it into the a specified div field (`#newSide`) it is limited to a kind of "magical border" on the left and bottom areas.

My example is on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QU994/9/).

Procedure:

1. Drag the yellow box to the middle of the grey area.
2. Resize the yellow box to the lower (or left) end of the grey area.

I have read aber a bug and tried differend settings of position: absolute / relative and with !important tag but i don't get it.

Any ideas on how to solve the problem? Is it a wrong CSS setting? (for me, it is neccessary to place the droppable area anywhere i want (not just at top:0px; left:0px;)

Many thanks anyway!

HTML Code:

```
<div id="editor">
  <div id="newSide"></div>
</div>
<div class="draggableItem"></div>
```

JS Code:

```
$(function() {

$( "#newSide" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
    }
});

$(".draggableItem").resizable({
                    containment: "#newSide",
                    grid: 1, maxHeight: 150, maxWidth: 200, minHeight: 20, minWidth: 20
                    })
                    .draggable({
                          containment: "#newSide",
                          grid: [1,1]
                    }); 
});
```

CSS:

```
#editor{
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid red;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
}

.draggableItem
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:yellow;
}

#newSide
{
    display:block;  
    width:401px;
    min-height:301px;
    height:301px;
    background-color:#444444;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this what you where looking for?

HTML Structure:

```
<div id="editor">
    <div id="newSide">
        <div class="draggableItem"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QU994/13/

Comment: Hi, already many thanks! But that's not exactly what i'm looking for - the draggable element should be dropped into the dragging area. (-> at the beginning the draggableItem should be outside of it)